# What should I do if i want to take an input in C++ but the integer is very long (eg. 1000101010101001)?

Tags: c++

What should I do if i want to take an input in C++ but the integer is very long (e.g. 1000101010101001)?
I tried using `long long int` but that didn't work.

```
int main()
{ 
  long int number = 14072020; 
  binaryeven(number); 
  int num2;
  binaryodd(number);
  checkeven(14072020,1101011010111000110101001);
  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Hint: strings are your friend.

Comment: For this specific case where you read a binary number and check if it's odd or even? Or in general?

Comment: there is an integer type for 64-bit number, Int64. You should use that type. If you operate the number which can't calculate with 64 bit, you should use string.

Comment: [The GNU MP Bignum Library](https://gmplib.org/)?

Comment: @ChungHuang there is no `Int64` in c++. There is `(unsigned) long long` and the typedefs in `#include <cstdint>`, e.g `std::uint64_t`

Answer (score 1):

If you need read from text a binary representation of some value just use `std::bitset`.

```cpp
std::bitset<32> x;
while(std::cin >> x) {
    std::cout << x << " = " << x.to_ullong() << '\n';
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/d3MGfK

---

If you need use [integral literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) in binary representation you can do it since C++14:

```cpp
checkeven(14072020, 0b1101011010111000110101001);
```

https://godbolt.org/z/nY3s3n

Answer (score 1):

You should read the value in a `std::string`, as "1101011010111000110101001".

Then, check the last digit. For binary, '0' is even, '1' is odd. For decimal, '0', '2', '4', '6', '8' are even, the others are odd.

No need to check anything but the last digit/bit.